# unwind seque loses navigaton bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a series of view controllers A,B,C embedded in a navigation controller N as in N,A,B,C.
When I go back from C to B using a swipe things work, but if I use the navigation bar back button then I see the view for B and the nav bar from A.

Any ideas?

Comment: Standard or custom button? Have you actually specified an unwind? What is it?

Comment: I created a push segue "SequeToImageView" on the storyboard with and initiate the segue programmatically with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SequeToImageView" sender:self];`  I don't do anything else.

Comment: And that's connected to the back button or where?

Comment: I ctrl clicked and dragged a seque from the VC controller B to the VC C.  The name of B is "conversation" and after the seque a link with that name appears in the navigation bar.  Swiping brings me back to B correctly, where as clicking on the nav bar link "conversation" brings me back to B, but the nav bar is then incorrect as it is the nav bar for A.